# ASP.NET MVC Passing action parameter to the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Let's say that I have a Action method like this:

```
public ActionResult Page(int? id)
{
}
```

The question is, how can I read 'id' parameter in View?

Comment: Have you tried something? generally putting it in the ViewBag is enough...

Comment: You don't read parameters in the view, you pass parameters from the view to the controller. If you need to pass the value of the parameter back to the view then set it in your model or the ViewBag.

Comment: @Tallmaris: I was wondering if there is some possibility to merge the information with passing model, but ViewBag seems to be ok. Thanks!

Comment: When you want to combine data from a model and other miscellaneous data, it is often useful to create a view model.

Comment: @Ben Robinson: Ok, I will try to use ViewBag. But, how does setting parameter to model will look like? Let's say my model is of type IEnumerable...

Comment: @Ben Robinson: I am new to ASP.NET MVC technology and never used (but had heard) about ViewModels. For now I think I will use ViewBag. Thanks for help!

Comment: As a workaround will do, but in the long run the ViewBag is not the right place. As Ben said, I would start reading around about ViewModels (which is just that, a model that aggregates all the info you want to send to the view).

Comment: @Tallmaris: I will read more about ViewModels. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code won't build successfully, until you return a view like this

```
public ActionResult Page(int? id)
{
    return View();
}
```

and because you want to return id to your view you can do
**Simple object**

```
public ActionResult Page(int? id)
{
    return View(id);
}
```

Just remember to accept the new value in your view, by dong the following at the top (very first line)

```
@model int?
```

**ViewModel approach**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    //Other properties here
}

 public ActionResult Page(int? id)
 {
     var myViewModel = new MyViewModel()
     {
         Id = id
     };
     return View(myViewModel);
 }
```

and then in your view

```
 @model MyViewModel
```

Comment: Whilst this will work, somehow i don't think a view based on a model that is a nullable int is that useful.

Comment: @BenRobinson I completely agree with you.  However he asked how to get the id to the view and this is valid and correct solution.  Sure we could use the viewbag, but I personally hate using the viewbag and think its messy.

Comment: @Johan: Actually my question isn't complete. In fact I am returning View with model as a parameter.

Comment: @user1334190 I have updated my answer using the ViewModel approach

Comment: @Johan: Thank's for answering. I will read more about ViewModels in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You can access parameters from Request in view as below

```
Request.Params["id"]
```